# How to filter certain notifications with OneSingal on Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, onesignal

I'm using OneSignal SDK (`onesignal: ^1.1.0`) with Flutter. I need to filter some types/categories of notifications for each user on my application. 
Is there any type of event that I can use for decide if show or not a notification?

My idea is to create different notifications categories. Every user will be able to choose which types of notifications he/she can receive.

At the moment I can only choose if receive or not all the notifications calling `setSubscription`:

```
OneSignal.shared.setSubscription(myBool);
```

If value is set to true the user can receive the notifications, if false he/she can't receive them.

This is my `main.dart` code:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:onesignal/onesignal.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  bool _areNotificationsEnabled = true;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    OneSignal.shared.init('myKey', iOSSettings: {
      OSiOSSettings.autoPrompt: false,
      OSiOSSettings.inAppLaunchUrl: true
    });

    OneSignal.shared
        .setInFocusDisplayType(OSNotificationDisplayType.notification);
    OneSignal.shared.setNotificationOpenedHandler(
        (OSNotificationOpenedResult handler) async {
      print('Notification opened');
      print(handler.notification.payload.additionalData.toString());
    });
    OneSignal.shared
        .setNotificationReceivedHandler((OSNotification notification) async {
      print("Notification received");
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: Container(
        child: SwitchListTile(
          value: _areNotificationsEnabled,
          title: Text('Enable notifications'),
          subtitle: Text('Turn on or off your notifications'),
          onChanged: (bool newValue) {
            OneSignal.shared.setSubscription(newValue);
            print(
                'Notifications state --> ${newValue ? 'Enabled' : 'Disabled'}');
            setState(() {
              _areNotificationsEnabled = !_areNotificationsEnabled;
            });
          },
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

HowdyE.Benedos,
You can use data tags to segment your users based on their preferences.

The ability to set data tags is incredibly powerful. You can store data attributes on each user. Tags are available on all OneSignal accounts and are a very popular feature among our customers. Users are tagged with attributes such as types of messages they want to receive, content categories, cart abandonment info, subscription status and user-preferences.

Read more here: https://onesignal.com/blog/data-integration-and-tagging-using-onesignal/

Comment: Finally we choose to use user_external_id (UUID) associated with player id. In our DB we store an UUID for every user. When the user login in our app, we tell to OneSignal to associate the user_external_id with the device player id. Then when we sent a notification we use "user_external_ids" instead of "player_ids"